# Is it possible to log any loglevel ony if error occurs in java with log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I was wondering if it is possible to create a logstack with log4j that would only been logged if an defined loglevel occurs.
For Example:
We have realy big logfiles and have to log a lot to find out how the user has gotten to this error.
But we only need this informations if an error occurs and not for every user.

Is there a way to handle this in log4j without getting active by myself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no out-of-the-box mechanism that would allow you to create a logstack in log4j and log it only if you decide to do that later (if an error occurs).

However, you could implement such feature by means of `Filter`s (yeah, by being active yourself). A filter might stack messages up in its buffer (it must be thread local or use some other technique to link the stack to the context) until it either detects that the stack must be cleared and a new one started (by some marker that indicates a new user request) or that an error occurs and the stack must be flushed to the log.